# Pregmatch for at least 3 letters and for minus and apostrophe

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex for a name validation.The rules are:

-must start with a letter;

-must have at least three letters(not only consecutive...anywere in the name);

-must accept minus (-) and apostrophe (')-**these are the only special characters that can be used** ...(not mandatory and anywere in the name).

Until now I have this code:

```
"/^[a-zA-Z]{3}+['-]+$/"
```

but this accepts only `three consucutive letters` and consecutive `'-`

Thank you!

---

**EDIT** Solved by **tommoyang**

Comment: Here's a tool for testing your regex in real-time: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: You apostrophe and minus are mandatory with this Regex.

Comment: Learn regular expressions. We are not here to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z'-]*?){3,}$/
```

The main body specifies any Alpha char, followed by any number (including 0) of the following chars. It's ungreedy, so you can repeat 3x to reach your requirement of 3 Alpha characters, and then the final

```
[A-Za-z'-]*?
```

block will grab everything else.

Comment: This is the right answer...thank you very much **tommoyang** !

best wishes!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you could do this in a single turn efficiently.

But something similar should work:

```
  if (
    preg_match("/^[a-z][a-z'-]{3,}$/i",$subject) &&
    strlen(preg_replace('/[\W_]/','',$subject))>=3
  ){
     ...
```

Or a less fast, but only regexp solution:

```
"/^([a-z][a-z'-]*?){3,}$/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]/'
```

Note the single quotes, otherwise your terminal `$` would be interpreted... But it is not required anyway...

Comment: This will match more than just alphabetic, minus and apostrophe.

Comment: @putvande Not required, since there is _no_ restriction as to what characters may occur. Those are just arbitrary characters recognized by the .* operators.

Comment: they aren't mandatory...but for example # or % signs are forbidden...so the only special characters can be ' and -

Comment: @AdiCrainic Where is it stated that those characters are "forbidden"?

Comment: _-must accept minus (-) and apostrophe (') ...(not mandatory and anywere in the name)_

Comment: @AdiCrainic And what does this tell about other characters? Nothing. It only states that _these_ characters must be accepted. Not more.

Comment: It is impressive how people downvote a clean and working solution because then _think_ they know better what is required than the OP does. If there were more restrictions then the OP should post them. He did _not_ post more restrictions. The regex I posted fullfills the posted requirements.

Comment: ok arkascha..it is my mistake a wasn't more clear...sorry for that