# regex and apostrophe

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My answer is almost like this one:
[Pregmatch for at least 3 letters and for minus and apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723375/pregmatch-for-at-least-3-letters-and-for-minus-and-apostrophe)

So, I need too a regex for a name validation. But my rules are a little different:

- must start with a letter;
- no numbers and no alphanumeric;
- must have at least three letters (also not only consecutive... anywere in the name) and max 20;
- can accept only one apostrophe (') or no one else -these are the only special characters that can be used ...(not mandatory and anywere in the name). it doesnt matters where you put the apostrophe

  for ex:

  d'amico => must be accepted;
  d'amico' => no 
  d''amico => no 
  'oneil => no
  dell'amore => yes 
  damico => yes 
  king kong => yes 
  io => no 
  io9 => no
  8888 => no
  aaa+++? => no

Until now I have this code:

```
<?php
...
    // Array errori
    $error = array(); // o $error = []; se hai una versione di php recente

    // Controllo il Nome Utente
    if(trim($nome) == ''){
        $error[] = 'Campo nome non compilato'; }

    if (ctype_alnum($nome)) 
        {$error[] = 'Se vuoi modificare il campo nome, assicurati che lo 
             stesso non contenga numeri al suo interno!'; }  

    if(strlen($nome) < 3 || strlen($nome) > 20){
        $error[] = 'Il campo nome deve contenere minimo 3 caratteri e massimo 20 caratteri'; }

    if (!preg_match("/^([A-Za-z|àèéìòù][A-Za-z'-]*?){3,}$/", $nome)) {
        $error[] = 'Il campo nome contiene caratteri non ammessi'; } 

...

?>

<html>...

<?php 
      if(!empty($error)){
         echo  '<center>';
         echo implode('<br/>', $error);
        echo  '</center>';
      }
   ?>

...
</html>
```

How can I combine everything into one string?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm curious: Why such rigid validation against somebody's name? It's understandable for things like emails and phone numbers, but when it comes to names and all of the various cultures that have different rules, wouldn't it make more sense to just accept a certain set of characters?

Comment: @maiorano84 simply to streamline the manual work that occurs after a user logging onto the form. there is no racism towards the name of anyone ... :) but if you have any proposal to do I accept it gladly.

Comment: Personally? I would just keep it limited to letters, spaces, dashes, and apostrophes. I wouldn't concern myself too much with users putting in something like `m''gorpkplzik`. For all I know, somebody's parents may have decided to name them by throwing a keyboard down some stairs. I think some trust needs to be placed in the user to put in valid information. I would suggest something like: `/^(?.*[a-z]{3})[a-z0-9\- \'àèéìòù]+$/i`. That will at least make sure you have 3 consecutive letters.

Comment: Sure is! Should be: `/^(?=.*[a-z]{3})[a-z0-9\- \'àèéìòù]+$/i`

Comment: As a note, I'm leaving numbers in, as I would personally accept something like "Jon Doe the 3rd". If numbers are unacceptable, it would look like: `/^(?=.*[a-z]{3})[a-z\- \'àèéìòù]+$/i`

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative lookahead you can assert that the string doesn't start with a `'`, whitespace, or contain 2 (or more) single quotes. Then you can just test that the string is between 3 and 20 characters long with your allowed character list.

```
(?!(.*?'.*?'|^[' ]))^[A-Za-z|àèéìòù ']{3,20}$
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QANVBo/1

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/659769

PHP Usage:

```
$array = array("d'amico", "dell'amore", "damico", "king kong", "io", "io9", "8888", "aaa+++?", "d'amico'", "d''amico", "'oneil");
foreach ($array as $term ) {
     if(preg_match("/(?!(.*?'.*?'|^[' ]))^[A-Za-z|àèéìòù ']{3,20}$/", $term)) {
          echo 'Matches:';
     } else {
          echo 'No Match:';
     }
     echo $term . "\n";
}
```

Comment: if (!preg_match("/(?!(.*?'.*?'|^[' ]))^[A-Za-z|àèéìòù ']{3,20}$/i", $nome)) {$error[] = 'Inserisci un nome valido!';}  it dont work with apostrophe e white space... so the name d'amico shows error!!! anyway thank you so match!

Comment: Can you update the `eval.in` to show the name you are using? Also I'm not sure why the `|` was in your original character class but I left that in, could be an issue (your description never mentioned it).

Comment: it could be wrong my array? i don't understand why it doesnt work!! i spent all the day in it.

Comment: What array? Can you provide a full example of what you're using?

Comment: i try php demo, you are posted, on my php page and it works!  but with your regex, no! but if i write:     
     if(!preg_match("/(?!(.*?'.*?'|^[' ]))^[A-Za-z|àèéìòù ']{3,20}$/", $nome)) {
  echo 'No Match :'; exit(); }
    
     if(preg_match("/(?!(.*?'.*?'|^[' ]))^[A-Za-z|àèéìòù ']{3,20}$/", $nome)) {
 echo 'Match:'; exit(); }

Comment: i try php demo, you are posted, on my php page and it works! but with your regex, no! but if i write: if(!preg_match("/(?!(.*?'.*?'|^[' ]))^[A-Za-z|àèéìòù ']{3,20}$/", $nome)) { echo 'No Match :'; exit(); } if(preg_match("/(?!(.*?'.*?'|^[' ]))^[A-Za-z|àèéìòù ']{3,20}$/", $nome)) { echo 'Match:'; exit(); } – every words with apostrophe goes to echo no match, like numbers or word with special characters

Comment: I'm not following can you post an example (note the above are not examples because no idea what `$nome` is)? Use https://3v4l.org/ incase it is something with PHP versions as well.

Comment: @Gianluis Success?